# CSharpCodeProvider Compiling Order

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

Is there a way to compile files automatically in the right order. 
Seems like 'CompileAssemblyFromFile' do not care about dependencies
before compiling. Way around ?

```
public bClass 
{
   public aClass FieldName; //Trows error not aClass type not found
}
```

Compile Order

```
1. bClass.css
2. aClass.cs
```

Comment: Show how you call the compiler. C# is multipass, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me in either order:

```
var pro = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var assem = pro.CompileAssemblyFromFile(new CompilerParameters(), "path/to/bClass.cs", "path/to/aClass.cs");
// or
var assem = pro.CompileAssemblyFromFile(new CompilerParameters(), "path/to/aClass.cs", "path/to/bClass.cs");
```

aClass.cs:

```
public class aClass 
{
}
```

bClass.cs:

```
public class bClass 
{
   public aClass FieldName;
}
```

Comment: My mistake. Made a typo.